# Passing variables to same page without query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change my code below so that I don't have to use query strings. I want to set two variables `yesID` and `noID`. I'm navigating from `default.aspx` to the same page `default.aspx`. Is this possible? If so how?

```
//get query string
if (Request.QueryString["yesId"] != null && Request.QueryString["noId"] != null)
{
    int yesPictureId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["yesId"]);
    int noPictureId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["noId"]);

    //Set rated image Items to Visible
    RatedImage.Visible = true;
    HyperLink1.Visible = true;
    RatedPicRating.Visible = true;

    //pass ratings to database
    Ratings PassRatings = new Ratings();
    PassRatings.InsertRatings(yesPictureId, 1);
    PassRatings.InsertRatings(noPictureId, 2);

    //Get total yes and nos and Do Calculation 
    Ratings GetNoVotes = new Ratings();
    int DATotalYesVotes = GetNoVotes.GetTotalNOVotes(1, yesPictureId);
    int DaTNoVotes = GetNoVotes.GetTotalNOVotes(2, yesPictureId);
    int DaTotalVotes = DATotalYesVotes + DaTNoVotes;
    double Percentage = ((double)DATotalYesVotes / (double)DaTotalVotes) * 100;
    //Round percentage
    Percentage = Math.Round(Percentage, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    //Insert New percentage
    Picture UpdatePictureTating = new Picture();
    UpdatePictureTating.UpdateRatings(yesPictureId, (int)Percentage);

    //Create pictue object
    Picture RatedPic = new Picture();
    DataTable DARatedPicture = RatedPic.GetRatedPicByQueryString(yesPictureId);

    //Assign Location and Rating to variables
    foreach (DataRow row in DARatedPicture.Rows)
    {
        // firstRatedPicId = row["PicID"].ToString();
        //secondNoPicId = firstYesPicId;
        //holds member Id for profile link
        int MemberID = (int)row["MemberID"];
        RatedPicnameLabel.Text = row["MemberName"].ToString() + "'s profile";
        HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Member.aspx?UserID=" + MemberID;
        RatedPicRating.Text = "Banged Rating: " + row["PicRating"].ToString() + "%";
        RatedImage.ImageUrl = "Pictures/" + row["PicLoc"];
        RatedImage.PostBackUrl = "Member.aspx?UserID=" + MemberID;
    }

}
else
{
    //If we dont have any ratied pictures hide those elements
    RatedImage.Visible = false;
    HyperLink1.Visible = false;
    RatedPicRating.Visible = false;
}
```

I'm setting the variables below. I don't want to use a query string though.

```
FirstPicLink.PostBackUrl = "default.aspx?yesId=" + firstYesPicId + "&noId=" + firstNoPicId;
SecondPicLink.PostBackUrl = "default.aspx?yesId=" + secondYesPicId + "&noId=" + secondNoPicId;
```

I'm thinking something like this. But how do I store those variables? Won't they be lost once the page is reloaded.

```
yesID = 1
NoID = 2
FirstPicLink.PostBackUrl = "default.aspx";
SecondPicLink.PostBackUrl = "default.aspx";
```

Answer (score 0):

Session is your friend!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By default, controls that cause a postback (like button) submit the page back to itself. So you don't need to use the PostBackUrl property.

With regards to persisting the value of the variables:

a) You can store them in a hidden field : check the  control.

```
<asp:HiddenField id="yesID" runat="server" value="1"/>
```

b) You can use session variables..

```
Session["yesID"] = 1;
```

c) Viewstate

```
ViewState["yesID"] = 1;
```

and then read them again during page load.

Answer (score 0):

IMO VeiwState should work best for you as you are posting the data back to the same page, and far more efficient than Session for your particular case

```
ViewState["yesID"] = 1;
ViewState["noID"] = 2;
```